# How can we remove a ':' characters from a string?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have strings like

```
@lle @mme: #crazy #upallnight:
```

I would like to remove the words which starts with either `@` or `#`. It works perfectly fine if those words doesn't contain the ':' character. However, that ':' character is left whenever I delete the words. Therefore I decided to replace those ':' characters before I delete the words using a string.replace() function. However, they are still not removed.

`String example = "@lle @mme: #crazy #upallnight:";`

`example.replace(':',' ');`

The result : `@lle @mme: #crazy #upallnight:`

I am pretty stuck here, anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: example = example.replace ....

Comment: In other words, replace returns a new string, not modifies in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
example = example.replaceAll(" +[@#][^ ]+", "");
```

What this will do is replace any substrings in your string that match the regex pattern `[@#][^ ]+` with the empty string. Since that pattern matches the words you want to dump, it'll do what you want.

[Demo of the pattern on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KC39eL/1)

Comment: will that include the words ending in :

Comment: Yes, it will. I've added a regex demo.

Comment: I would like to remove all the special character words too - meaning words which contains the special character. Should I create a new question?

Comment: Yes, you should. Once a question has been answered, SO best practice is not to change its basic intent, which is what you would be doing by editing this one.

Comment: if the string has words like sund@y, it is removing the @y, is it possible to be the regex with only the characters starting with @ or #

Comment: @ChitKhine: Fixed now. As an added bonus, it'll clean up extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

From Java docs:

```
String s = "Abc: abc@:";

String result = s.replace(':',' ');
```

Output in variable `result`= Abc  abc@

I think you forgot to store the returned result of replace() method in some other String variable.